# How to actualize sequence for DataTables's rowReorder extension?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using rowReorder extension for DataTables.

I got a button to remove some rows with https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove(), but after clicking it, the corresponding sequence number is missing.

How can I actualize this sequence, so it contains the new rows count ?

I tried to manually update the sequence field value, but if you try to drag and drop a row after this, the sequence numbers appears in double.

Here is my code

```js
var t = $('#mytable').DataTable({
 'rowReorder': true,
  'dom' : '<t>',
});

$('.delbutton').on('click', function() {
 t
    .row( $(this).parents('tr') )
    .remove()
    .draw();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.0/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.0/css/rowReorder.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<table id="mytable" class="display" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <th>sequence</th>
    <th>datas</th>
    <th>delete</th>
  </thead>
  <tdboy>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td class="delbutton">x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td class="delbutton">x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>dolor</td>
      <td class="delbutton">x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>sit</td>
      <td class="delbutton">x</td>
    </tr>
  </tdboy>
</table>
```

Thanks,